# How to see what commands a particular login session used?

Tags: debian, server-administration

I have a debian server and I am the adminstrator for the server. The server hasn't been working correctly and I would like to see what commands were executed by the last 3-4 users who logged in (separated by each login session, since the same user logged in more than once). Is there any way I can accomplish this? I am the root user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [a decent article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-log-user-activity-using-process-accounting.html) that explains various auditing tools, including the one you want, `lastcomm`. It's part of **acct** package, so do:

```
sudo apt-get install acct
```

The output is very detailed, so you may want to filter on which commands were run:

```
$ lastcomm --command wajig apt-get
wajig                  tshepang pts/7      0.00 secs Tue Oct  8 22:56
wajig                  tshepang pts/7      0.00 secs Tue Oct  8 22:56
apt-get          S     root     pts/7      0.52 secs Tue Oct  8 22:56
apt-get           F    root     pts/7      0.00 secs Tue Oct  8 22:56
wajig                  tshepang pts/7      0.00 secs Tue Oct  8 22:47
apt-get          S     root     pts/7      0.45 secs Tue Oct  8 22:47
apt-get           F    root     pts/7      0.00 secs Tue Oct  8 22:47
```

Further info, e.g. the meaning of the fields, can be found on [that article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-log-user-activity-using-process-accounting.html).

Answer (score 0):

It depends of the shell, if bash you can try (as root):

```
cat /home/user_you_are_looking_for/.bash_history
```

Comment: This won't separate by login session. One workaround is to store a master bash history for each user, then XOR it with the bash history at end of the session and then save it by session id.